# Boot Linux while running Windows

Tags: windows

I will be traveling for a month, without bringing my computer. I might only have access to public computers running Windows in Internet cafes. While I'm traveling, I would like to SSH to my Linux server to fix some bugs if occurs.

What is the easiest way for me to run Linux on a Windows machine, and have access to the Internet without rebooting the computer. Once I run Linux on top of Windows, I will also have Internet access immediately without the need to reconfigure.

In fact, a Linux with terminal is enough.

Preferably to run this on a USB flash drive.

Comment: Running on OS inside some other OS will require you to run some VM. Do you really want to run a whole OS on the windows box or do you only want to ssh to your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `ssh` from some public windows box into some linux server.

First you cannot trust that windows box. There might be some malware on that box storing your password and afterwards allowing others to access your server, too.

If you don't care about this, you could hope that the windows box is not secured and allows you to download and run arbitrary tools. In this case you could use  [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to access your server.

Otherwise the windows box probably allows only access to normal websites. In this case you could install some [web-based ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) on your server to allow access.

But whatever you do, you will get in trouble unless you bring your own computer.

Comment: I think web-based ssh in not secure enough..I mean totally web servers that give you access are not secure enough...right?

Comment: If you care about security you *really* have to bring your own computer. But if you really must use an inherently unsecure public computer, SSL+password should be as secure as SSH+password. (Just double check the servers fingerprint and hope no one is grabbing you password or hijacking your connection.) You might also set up OTP passwords to make sure your used password is useless afterwards.

Comment: Ok I agree with you...But I put my idea across and tell the web-based services usually are insecure as well...Thanks...you are right

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

`putty` and `winscp` from [HERE](http://filehippo.com/)

Search them in that link download and work...

Answer (score 0):

> What is the easiest way for me to run Linux on a Windows machine

[Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl) sound like what you want. It's an official compatibility layer from Microsoft and Canonical that lets you run Linux binaries on top of the Windows kernel. You will have access to all standard Linux tools and the program repositories that you had if you were running a "normal" Ubuntu/Linux distro.

There is also a similar tool called [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), though techncally it only provides a Linux-like environment without actually letting you run "vanilla" Linux binaries.

If you only want to run SSH though, as mentioned in another reply, you will be better off just using a native Windows SSH client such as Putty.